# Activity Manager - No longer want

Tags: android, android-activity, logcat

An app I am creating needs to run, potentially, 24/7.

I was testing it yesterday, when after a couple of hours, the logcat showed the following:

> ActivityManager( 351 ) No longer want com.company.appname (pid 13585): empty for 12673s

This particular app has been tested before, on a couple of devices, without issue.

The app is pretty basic, dealing with asset downloads from a server and ultimately a WebView that loads a local HTML file. This is the activity/view that was active when this error occurred.

Comment: This may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14043442/no-longer-want-activitymanager-not-a-service-issue

Comment: Sorry, but I am very new to Android Development, so I am unsure how to go about fixing this just from reading that post. Could you possibly point me in the correct direction, in terms of some code to use?